# How do I create a tar.gz file with the contents of the webpack output directory?

Tags: webpack

I have this React front end all nicely packed, uglified and chunked in my `/build` folder. And I want to automate the process of gzipping the directory into a snapshot and uploading it to my maven repository.

I've been looking through the documentation and cannot for the life of me figure out if I can set this up in my `webpack.config.js` and automate it after the contents have been packed.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a plugin just for that. The terminal command is quite simple though and so could be included in your `build` script for npm or gulp or whatever else you might use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `webpack-shell-plugin` to archive compiled files. My compiled files were is 'dist' directory.

1. I installed this plugin using npm.
2. Imported it with `const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin')`.
3. Created "archive" shell command:

   `const CREATE_ARCHIVE = 'tar czvf --ignore-failed-read ' + paths.base() +        '/bundle.tar.gz' + ' -C ' + paths.dist() + ' . '`
4. Created and added shell plugin with

   `webpackConfig.plugins.push(
       new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
       //.. other plugins,
       new WebpackShellPlugin({
         onBuildExit: [CREATE_ARCHIVE],
         safe: true
       })
     )`

It creates build.tar.gz in the root of the project after you run your webpack build.